# VPN -> Orbot - possible?

Tags: orbot

I want my apps to connect to the internet like this:

Android Phone -> VPN -> Orbot

So far, I've been able to achieve this with OrWall (turning off transparent proxying in Orbot and selecting the apps I want to torify in OrWall).

Unfortunately, OrWall is out of date and will not be updated any further. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

As I've written before in Tor.SE - you need a *separate* box to route traffic to prevent network leaks 100%. I'd recommend to use a Raspberry Pi or Orange Pi PC board to do so - it will be secure, a *way more faster*, and will save your Phone/Tablet battery life. For example Nexus 7 lives with just Orbot for 1 day and some hours, without Orbot(with a routing box) - 3-4 days no problem! The problem that can **never** be solved by installing something on a phone is that you need to control all the processes, especially on boot sequence, and give no root permission to programs. You can use a wireshark/tcpdump and just boot your you-think-torified phone or tablet and take a look at traffic: at early stages it *will* jailbreak and go online without Tor